# Is it possible to publish apps in Xcode 8/Swift 3 Beta for iOS 9?

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am working on an app and thinking about upgrading to the Xcode 8 Beta and using Swift 3. In its current state, is it possible to publish apps for iOS 9? Obviously when the full version comes out, I should be able to, but what if I want to publish something in the next month or two?

Comment: No. This has never been possible for any beta ever. You need to build your app on a non beta version of Xcode which means 7 at the moment and so swift 2.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/

> Apps that are created using beta versions of Xcode or that are built for beta versions of an OS will not be accepted on the App Store.