# xcode 8 beta unable to upload to testflight

Tags: app-store, testflight, xcode8, ios10

I was using testflight with xcode 8 beta for the last few days.  yesterday it stopped working with the error:

> ERROR ITMS-90512: "Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk
>   portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   example.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib is 10.0 which is
>   greater than the maximum allowed value of 9.3." ...

This is repeated for other frameworks.

My build deployment target is iOS 9.3

I understand this not being allowed for apps uploaded for release.  But why would the restriction be there for testflight apps?  The point of testflight is to test out your changes.

Swift 3.0 is so different that reverting back to xcode 7.3 is not really an option for me.  Just wondering why it worked initially but stopped suddenly and if anybody has found a solution to use testflight with xcode 8 beta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to publish apps in Xcode 8/Swift 3 Beta for iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979527/is-it-possible-to-publish-apps-in-xcode-8-swift-3-beta-for-ios-9)

Comment: my question deals specifically with testflight and not the app store for release.  also i have uploaded to testflight with xcode8 beta and wondering why it stopped suddently.

Comment: Testflight and app store builds are the same, that's why I think this question is a duplicate.  If you were able to upload before, then maybe something has changed on Apple's end.

Comment: i think so.  i'll keep trying or just wait for xcode 8 release.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apps that are created using beta versions of Xcode or that are built for beta versions of an OS will not be accepted on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8 beta 6 is allowing uploading of builds of iOS 10

Comment: So only if target is IOS 10?